# how to set zoom level/view of leaflet map

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, r-leaflet

I have a map in `leaflet` in RShiny which have markers plotted and once I click a marker it adds circles to map showing all the related points to the marker.

What I want to do is to set zoom/view of the map in such a way that all the related circles are visible.

The number of circles varies as per markers i.e. some marker have 1 or 2 circles while some have more. Also, the location of circles varies across the USA so they can be placed in one city or another state.

Following is the code I am using to add circles to existing map

```
  proxy <-leafletProxy("map",data = df)%>%
  clearMarkers()%>%
  addCircleMarkers(lat = ~lat,lng = ~lng,layerId = ~circle_pt,fillColor = 
 'green',opacity = 0.5,color = 'red',fillOpacity = 1)%>% clearPopups()%>%
  addPopups(lat=~lat,lng=~lng,~as.character(circle_pt))
```

map=original map with markers
df=lat lng of circles with associated properties of selected marker in map

[image: original map where markers are shown]

[image: circles are shown on marker click event]

I want to set zoom level as shown in figure 2.

Kindly help me to identify how to calculate optimal zoom level in leaflet in `shiny`.

Regards,

Comment: please try to provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to set your initial view, you can use:

```
setView(lng, lat, zoom = zoom_level)
```

which is straight from the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/leaflet/versions/1.1.0/topics/setView).

Unless you provide more information, nobody will be able to understand the part where you're saying "in such a way that all the related circles are visible."

Comment: I have added images for further clarification. image 2 shows zoom level that is required.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you're app works and whats in the original call to leaflet. But maybe the following example might help you.

I store the click on the markers, filter the data according to the clicked layerId, get the min/max lat/long of the resulting data and then use `fitBounds()` to set the "zoom" level. (You could also use `flyToBounds` with the same arguments, which should make a smoother transition to the selected markers, but its still too buggy for me at least)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(leaflet)

cords <- data.frame(
  lng = runif(100, 14, 18),
  lat = runif(100, 54, 58),
  circle_pt = sample(1:20, size = 100, replace = T)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map", height = "700px")
) 

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(data = cords) %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      addCircleMarkers(lat = ~lat,lng = ~lng, layerId = ~circle_pt, fillColor = 'green',
                     opacity = 0.5,color = 'red',fillOpacity = 1) 
  })

  observeEvent(input$map_marker_click, {
    clickid = input$map_marker_click$id
    cordsNew = cords[cords$circle_pt==clickid,]

    maxLong = max(cordsNew$lng)
    maxLat = max(cordsNew$lat)
    minLong = min(cordsNew$lng)
    minLat = min(cordsNew$lat)

    proxy <-leafletProxy("map", data = cordsNew)
    proxy %>%
      addCircleMarkers(lat = ~lat,lng = ~lng, layerId = ~circle_pt, fillColor = 'green',
                       opacity = 0.5,color = 'red',fillOpacity = 1) %>% 

      fitBounds(minLong,minLat,maxLong,maxLat) %>% 

      clearPopups() %>%
      addPopups(lat=~lat,lng=~lng,~as.character(circle_pt))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you can define an interval varint <- findInterval() and that pass to setView

```
varint <- findInterval()
setView(lng= lng,lat = lat, zoom = varint)
```

in findInterval, try to put some range of data with the distance between all points

EDIT:

try to calculate the distance between the farthest points that appear.

```
    proxy <-leafletProxy("map",data = df) %>%
        setView(
          lng = click$lng, 
          lat=click$lat,
          zoom=findInterval(someaverageofyourpoints, c(25,75,100,250,400,750,1000))
)
```

you can sum other values to findinterval, findinterval()+ 1 .. 2.. 4 ...5 for setting zoom level if findintervalset a tiny value

Comment: I have added images for further clarification. image 2 shows zoom level that is required.

Comment: @AwaisHassan i dont know if is the best option but i tried to help you ;)

Comment: It gives me following error if i use setView in proxy command:Error in metaData: argument "data" is missing, with no default

Comment: i edit my code, delete bad %>% proxy %>% i dont know if that is the error.